# change data in column

Tags: r

I have boxscore data from the NFL and some of the data is obviously incorrect.  For example for some games the number of sacks is negative, which is impossible.  This column is named `SackNumOff`.  How do I change any negative values in this column to zero?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
dat$columnname[dat$columnname < 0] = 0
```

Replaces all negative numbers by 0. The idea is that you can use a subset `[]` both to extract a subset and assign values to a subset.